# MS Word: keyboard shortcut for "Layout -> Breaks -> Page"

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

(A) The `InsertPageBreak`command (`Ctrl`+`Enter`) in MS Word will insert a paragraph character, the page break character, and a second paragraph character, as highlighted in the image below. Moreover, there will be a format change of indents and spacing on the paragraph character.
[image]

(B) However, when I choose Layout -> Breaks -> Page, this will do something slightly different: it will insert the page break directly at the cursor position, plus a paragraph character, retaining the current format:

[image]

I've tried to search the list of commands (in Customize Ribbon -> Keyboard Shortcuts), in order to assign a keyboard shortcut to this second behaviour (B), but so far, I've found no corresponding command.

- `InsertBreak` will bring up a menu from which to choose
- `InsertNewPage` is equivalent to repeating twice `InsertPageBreak`

How can I achieve this second behaviour (B) with ONE shortcut (not a combination) ?

EDIT: My goal is to be able to assign `CTRL`+ `ENTER` to such behaviour (B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Alt` followed by `P` followed by `B` followed by `P`.

This is the Ribbon shortcuts and will show up in tooltips after you press the `Alt` key. It is the equivalent of using the mouse.

Otherwise, you can create a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro. Here is my article on the Microsoft website on [assigning keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Here is such a macro:

```
Sub PageBreakInsert()
'   Charles Kenyon
'   Mimics insertion from Breaks menu
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=0
End Sub
```

Comment: is there any chance I could assign this to a single shortcut? I'd like to reassign Ctrl+Enter to that behaviour

Comment: Second downside is that it will switch the tabs to 'Layout', which is unpractical while editing.

Comment: No, you cannot. You could perhaps do a macro and create a keyboard shortcut for that. It seems like overkill, though. There is no problem with the switch to the Layout tab, really. Continue editing. Most of your tools are still available through the right-click context menu.

Comment: Thanks. I've recorded a macro, that's just what I needed. If you can edit that into your answer it would be great. Anyway, problem solved.